# unexpected jquery module behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a plugin that will help to simplify the display of huge data on the client side, but the plugin doesn't work as expected.

Below a sample:

HTML

```
<div id="div1" class='test'>

</div>
<div id="div2" class='test'>
```

Script

```
(function($) {
  var context = $(this);
  var methods = {
    init: function() {
      context.on('click', function() {
        console.log(context.attr('id'))
      })
    }
  }

  $.fn.sample = function(methodOrOptions) {
    context = $(this)
    if (methods[methodOrOptions]) {
      return methods[methodOrOptions].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1))
    } else if (typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || !methodOrOptions) {
      return methods.init.apply(this, arguments)
    } else {
      $.error('Method ' + methodOrOptions + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip')
    }
  }
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.test').each(function(e, ui) {
    $(this).sample();
  })
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0767weu/)

in this sample I am expected that when the user clicks on the first div, it will write in the console div1 and when user clicks on the second div, div2 will be written on the console, however, the console was writing div2.

what is my mistake and why its not working as expected?

Comment: var context = $(this);  Huh?  'this' in that context would be the IIFE, no?  What is that (intended to be) doing?

Comment: There is only one `context` variable. Calling the method second time overwrites what's been set the first time.

Comment: @Juhana I am not expert in jQuery modules yet. I am working from c# background, how to achieve that each sample store its own variables ( encapsulation) like the c# class?

Comment: to explain my point, why i cannot get 2 different objects and each object has its own variables and methods but both for the same class "sample"

Comment: As mentioned above, context is a global outside of that function, so it is not 'its own'.  Also your not passing in the parameter to sample() that it appears to be expecting.  Also since your constructing your methods.init based off of what context is originally, which is completely invalid, that's not going to work as you expect it either.

Comment: @Taplar any resource or hint or code snippet that put me on correct track would be highly appreciated

Comment: Anything that is based on context can't be a global.  You'll need to access them within their context scope.  I would suggest starting small.  Try getting your sample to only bind on each of the elements and do what you want it to do, before you start trying to work with the passed in options.  Change your question to start there and we can help you along.

Comment: The constructor is so complex that it's hard to tell what part of it is necessary (did you just copy-paste it from somewhere, or does all that have a specific purpose?) but why can't you just pass the context to the init function as a normal argument? As in `methods.init(this)`

Comment: Or, since `this` is already bound to the init function, `context` is unnecessary altogether because it's supposed to be just a shortcut to `$(this)` so you could just do `var context = $(this)` inside the init function.

Comment: @Juhana context is there because other methods need it to do other things, my purpose is to plug sample on an element x, then element x will get some events and use can call methods to refresh which is defined in sample plugin, I gave this small sample to narrow my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a very boiled down start to what you were trying to do.  See what you think...

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.sample = function () {
        //'this' is already a jQuery object since sample is a function of $.fn
        //if this does not contain any elements, there's nothing to do
        if (!this.length) return;

        this.each(function(){
            //wrap the iterated element
            var $element = $(this);

            $element.on('click', function () {
                console.log($element.attr('id'));
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    $('.test').sample();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `context` scope needs to be fixed.
Just change the first part from this:

```
var context = $(this);
  var methods = {
    init: function() {
      context.on('click', function() {
        console.log(context.attr('id'))
      })
    }
  }
```

To this:

```
  var methods = {
    init: function() {
      var context = $(this);
      context.on('click', function() {
        console.log(context.attr('id'))
      })
    }
  }
```

Also remove this line:
`context = $(this)`

I also updated the jsFiddle.

Comment: in my project there are many functions depending on the context variable to draw things and so on. I think i will not be able to access the context object from other functions

Comment: if you have multiple functions similar to `init`, then you can just create a context variable in each function.